# How to find a "virtual" mathematics conference?

Tags: mathematics, conference, visiting

How can I find conferences in mathematics which accept guest articles/notes *without the guest physically visiting the conference*?

I have two problems which prevent me to physically visit conferences: 1. no money to pay for air tickets; 2. bad spoken English.

Can I nevertheless contribute to proceedings of a conference?

I found one such conference, but my article was judged not on-topic and rejected. It was the only conference I ever seen without the requirement to physically travel there to participate as an author.

Again: My question is *how* to find a conferences. Maybe you can suggest a specific Internet site(s) listing such conferences?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this? Unless you're in a field where conferences are the main publication venue (which I don't think you are?), then what is the benefit of submitting to a conference that you aren't attending, rather than submitting to a journal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mathematics research is mostly published in journals, sometimes books. Not conferences. Submit your papers to journals instead. You do not need to travel or speak to do that.

Conferences in mathematics are pretty much exclusively an affair of presenting your own research live in front of a mostly captive audience, and talking to the other participants between the presentations. A "virtual conference" (an online list of notes?) fills none of the missions, so I do not expect many to exist.

Even things called "proceedings" work much more like journals than conferences, to my knowledge. Most conferences have no proceedings — at best a list of abstracts online, perhaps even a copy of the slides if any.

(I have heard of (one) conference happening in two cities with live retransmission of talks from city A to city B and vice-versa, but that does not seem to be what you are looking for.)

Comment: I want to submit a review of my free e-book rather than an article. (At least some of) conferences accept books reviews, but most journals don't. Or can you point me a journal which may accept my review of my research book?

Comment: @porton I do not know any journal or conference that publishes book reviews. Especially not by the author of the book...?! The closest is Math Reviews (AKA MathSciNet) or ZBMath, but they do not take submissions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly similar thing called double conferences (i.e. the conference is conducted at two different physical locations and are connected by a video stream). This is not exactly what you are searching for but essentially a virtual conference is a conference that is held at *N* different physical locations (where *N* is the number of participants) so it is not that different from a double conference. An example: https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/HAMP.